# Consequences of factoring and discrete log in $P/Poly$

Tags: complexity-theory, factoring

What is the consequence of factoring and discrete log being in $P/poly$?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: The many papers relying on the hardness of factoring or discrete log would become moot and irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be pretty much no interesting consequences, from a complexity-theoretic perspective.  See [Consequences of Factoring being in P?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5096/5038) on CSTheory.  (Any consequence of factoring being in P/poly would also be a consequence of factoring being in P; but as the answers to that question state, there are basically no known complexity-theoretic consequences to factoring being in P.)

A Google search for "consequences of factoring in P/poly" also turns up [Factoring Could be Easy](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/factoring-could-be-easy/).